# Strictly pseudo-contraction maps on bounded subsets of a Hilbert space are bounded.

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, normed-spaces

Suppose that $T:\,K \rightarrow K$ is a strictly pseudo-contraction where $K$ is a bounded subset of a Hilbert space, then $T$ is bounded.

The operator $T,$ is said to be a strict pseudo-contraction if there exists $k<1$ such that 
$$\|Tx-Ty\|^{2}\leq \|x-y\|^{2} +k\|(I-T)x-(I-T)y\|^{2}, \;\forall \;x,y\in H.$$

**My trial**

For each $n\in \mathbb{N}$, let $x_n\in K.$ Then, $\{x_n\}$ is bounded. Thus,

\begin{align}
\|Tx_n\|^{2}&=\|Tx_n-T0+T0\|^{2}\\&\leq \|Tx_n-T0\|^{2}+2\|Tx_n-T0\|\|T0\|+\|T0\|^{2} \\&\leq 2\|Tx_n-T0\|^{2}+2\|T0\|^{2} 
\\&\leq 2\left[ \|x_n-0\|^{2} +k\|x_n-Tx_n-T0\|^{2}\right] +2\|T0\|^{2} \\&= 2\|x_n\|^{2}+2\|T0\|^{2} +2k\|x_n-Tx_n-T0\|^{2}
\end{align}

I'm stuck here and don't know what to do. Any hints on moving forward? It might even be that my proposition is false. Counter-examples are also welcome.

Comment: Is $T$ linear? If not, how do you define 'bounded' for nonlinear operators? Should it be $\forall x,y \in K$ in the first displayed formula?

Comment: @gerw: I guess $T$ is nonlinear.